# How do I count the number of deleted rows in a MYSQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to find out whether a delete query executed properly. I know how many rows its supposed to delete, and I'd like to check that the number that were deleted, matches what's expected, from within the query itself.

How do I find out the number of rows that I just deleted, **from within a SQL query** running against MySQL? Separate statements are fine, as long as I can bundle them into one query.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

see MySQL ROW_COUNT function here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count

Comment: I doubt that counts as what OP meant by *from within a SQL Query*

Comment: Can I call that function from within a query?

Comment: Yes I can. SELECT ROW_COUNT();

Comment: @blueberryfields - I (wrongly it seems) assumed you needed your delete statement to return the count. This is a *seperate* statement, *after* the delete. You might want to adjust the question to clear that up.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers You did not wrongly assume. Rather, the OP wrongly asked "from within a SQL query" since the OP accepts ROW_COUNT as an answer.  The OP probably meant **from within a Stored Procedure**, since stored-procedures is tagged.

Answer (score 14):

this is the query what you want,
**SELECT ROW_COUNT()**

```
mysql> DELETE FROM t WHERE i IN(1,2);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT ROW_COUNT() as DelRowCount;
+-------------+
| DelRowCount |
+-------------+
|           2 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: +1 for providing a clear example to make it more comprehensible for future readers, but you could at least give credit to my original answer and blueberryfields' comment below it, since you basically copied those two. I would also add a sample table `t` with `i` attribute in your example to make it best.

Comment: Yes i did. @JanTuroň thanks for your valuable time.. i have gone through documentation from your answer and i kept what i tried. gave +1 answer already